# Create a WPF C# chart with Live Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I Use Live Chart. SeriesCollection passes a Line Series in which Values = Chart Values. In xaml in Binding, I pass SeriesCollection. I understand that only y-points are transmitted (I do not change anything by default). How to transmit x points? Tried in ChartValue by index, swears that the index is empty. And even if you initially set the size of Chart Values, the cells that are not filled on the chart are filled as Y = 0. Please help, been three days sitting on it.

> GenerateChart.cs:

```
public ChartValues<double> Points { get; set; }
        double[] arraySeries = new double[30];
        double[] array = new double[20];
        public LineSeries GenerateSeries(string axis)
        {
            Random randomSeries = new Random();
            ChartValues<double> series = new ChartValues<double>(new double[20]);

            if (axis == "Y")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    double randomValue = randomSeries.Next(1, 20);
                    if (!array.Contains(randomValue))
                    {
                        array[i] = randomValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i--;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    double randomValue = randomSeries.Next(1, 20);
                    if (!arraySeries.Contains(randomValue))
                    {
                        int index = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
                        arraySeries[index] = randomValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i--;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    if (arraySeries[i] != 0)
                    {
                        series.Insert(i, arraySeries[i]);
                    }
                }
                //series.AddRange(arraySeries);

            }
            Points = series;
            var testSeries = new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Test",
                Values = series
            };

            return testSeries;
        }
```

> RandomSeries.cs:

```
public SeriesCollection Series { get; private set; }

        public SeriesCollection SeriesX { get; private set; }

        public ChartValues<double> Points { get; private set; }
        double[] arraySeries = new double[30];
        double[] array = new double[20];
        public SeriesCollection BuidChart()
        {
            Random randomSeries = new Random();
            var generateChart = new GenerateChart();

            Series = new SeriesCollection 
            {
                generateChart.GenerateSeries("Y")
            };
            Points = generateChart.Points;
            return Series;
        }
```

> ModelView.cs:

```
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
        public ChartValues<double> Points { get; set; }
        public RandomSeries randomSeries;
        public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }
        public string[] Labels { get; set; }
        public SeriesCollection SeriesCollectionX { get; set; }
        public void BuildFunction()
        {
            //Points.Clear();
            //SeriesCollection.Clear();
            randomSeries = new RandomSeries();
            SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();
            Points = new ChartValues<double>();
            SeriesCollection.AddRange(randomSeries.BuidChart());
            //Points.AddRange(randomSeries.Points);
            //SeriesCollection.AddRange(randomSeries.BuidChart());
            //Points.AddRange(randomSeries.Points);
            Labels = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jan1", "Feb1", "Mar1", "Apr1", "May1" };
        }
```

> MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:ModelView/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="257*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="536*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0" >
            <!--<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Y" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>-->
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="X" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
```

> Result program:
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTHDu.png)

Comment: Please show us the exact code.

Comment: [link](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Observable%20Point) - here is example in documentation, if you need to solve some problem please paste a code + xaml

Comment: @Kaspar Thanks, but I didn't find the answer in the documentation. Probably due to translation problems

Comment: I got a little problem with understand a problem, could you apply some desired output of chart? What you mean by transmit x point?

Comment: if you initialize the chart values by ChartValues<double> series = new ChartValues<double>(new double[20]); the default values will be zero, are you sure you fill all the values that is not equal to zero?

Comment: @Kaspar X - index. Y - value. For example i have a points: 0;5 and 5;3 (X;Y). And in the array between indices 0 and 5 there will be zero values. I need it to skip them, don't display(draw)

Comment: Ok, I think I got your problem, give me a 15-20 minutes, I will write a solution

Comment: @Kaspar I can with you as the contact, there is another a small question? :)

Comment: Yes sure! Ask me what you want ;) or another question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok in LiveChart there is possiblity to use ObservablePoint which represent X,Y position in the chart.

You need to add proper namespace to use these

```
using LiveCharts.Defaults;
```

I modfied two things in your Function, first I change definition and initialization of to ChartValues to by empty and typeof of ObservablePoint, so later we will dynamic fill these. You need also to change Points object to be type of ObservablePoint

```
ChartValues<ObservablePoint> series = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
```

And also modified the filling of these series object to add only non-zero:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if (arraySeries[i] != 0)
    {
        series.Add(new ObservablePoint(i, arraySeries[i]));
    }
 }
```

It will not draw zero-y-point between non-zero.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what I'd do without you. Did you use Live Chart yourself or was it the first time you encountered it?

Comment: your welcome, I am using it a lot so do not worry you do not know that ;)